# sbt-release plugin: version increment does not write on disk

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-release

I am adding the plugin to a project (https://github.com/IllinoisCogComp/saul/pull/372/files) and now trying to use it in order to automatically bump the version number upon release. When I try `release` (inside sbt) I can see (via `version`) that the version has been incremented; but after `reload`ing the version is back to the previous one. Also nothing is being written to `version.sbt` file. Any ideas where things might go wrong?

Comment: Did you forget to remove the version setting here in the build.sbt? https://github.com/IllinoisCogComp/saul/pull/372/files#diff-fdc3abdfd754eeb24090dbd90aeec2ceL23

Comment: I removed the version since I think sbt-release gets overriden by that. So just kept the version in `version.sbt`

Comment: I think I'm having the same basic problem. sbt-release seems to work except that it doesn't automatically increment the version number. Every time it runs, it just keeps re-using the same version number.

Comment: I don't know how but somehow I got it working. Check this out: https://github.com/CogComp/saul/blob/master/build.sbt

Comment: Arg. Dumb mistake on my part. Our file build.sbt still had the hardcoded version in it.